# How to read Youtube url from database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am reading my database that contains various columns along those a varchar(500) named video_games_trailer that has the url's of youtube videos. So far everything is displaying fine but in the position that the video should be I get the following:

```
Not Found 
The requested URL /Project/<embed width= was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an 
ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I am displaying the columns with the code below

```
 <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>

        <tr>
              <td><iframe width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" 
                allowfullscreen src="<?php echo 
                $row['video_games_trailer'];?>"></iframe></td>
       </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

In the database I 've put

```
<embed width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/whatever">
```

Wherever I looked that was the proposed method, am I missing something and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Don't put the `iframe` you already built the HTML in the DB. It'd be better to just store the URL in the DB. You could do some whacky `replace` with `locate` to update the DB so that column just gets the URLs.

Comment: ... so start with something like`substr(test, 1, (locate('src="', HTMLCOLUMN) + 4))` (likely to get very messy) or you could just parse the value and pull the `src` value. http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though if you're storing

`<embed width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/whatever">`

you should in fact be echoing out the following

```
 <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>

        <tr>
              <td><?php echo 
                $row['video_games_trailer'];?>"></td>
       </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

However, you're better off just storing say the watch ID part of the URL or just the URL.

Comment: Thank you it works even though  when I press the play  play I get an error occurred probably I made a mistake on the url on my part. Now I will look on finding out how to do it without writing html inside the database.